# Best way to to give JQuery DatePicker a locale based date format in Spring MVC web app?

Tags: java, spring, date-format

I'm working on a Spring 3 MVC application and there are JQuery date pickers which I want to give a date format which is based on the user's locale. I looked at at using an @ModelAttribute annotated controller method but I couldn't see a how to get the request context.

Current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <![CDATA[
        $( "#startDate").datepicker({
            showOn: "both",
            buttonImage: "${calendarIconUrl}",
            dateFormat:'yy/mm/dd',
            minDate:0
        });
    ]]>
</script>
```

So it's the `'yy/mm/dd'` I want to replace with a locale based date format.

EDIT: So I found http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/Localization but now I need to work out how to get the country code from the browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem where the locale was set by the server environment (in contrast to browser locales as required). I "translated" a Java locale to a JQuery Datepicker Locale this way:

```
Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
String datepickerLocale;
if(locale.getLanguage().equals("de")){
    datepickerLocale = "de"; // only "de", no country code
} else if (locale.getLanguage().equals("en")){
    if(locale.getCountry().equals("GB")){
        datepickerLocale = "en-GB"; // en-GB must be set explicitly
    } else if(locale.getCountry().equals("US")){
        datepickerLocale = ""; // en-US is default
    }
}
// [...] more locales if needed, see docs for Datepicker Localization
uiModel.addAttribute("datepickerLocale", datepickerLocale);
```

and then set in view:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional['${datepickerLocale}'] );
```

Getting the locale from the browser (request) should be something like this (untested)

```
RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request).resolveLocale(request)
```

UPDATE: I had to implement a DateEditor for validation that tells Spring which locale to use for the submitted data.